# iTextSharp throwing exception set to nothing

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am trying to convert HTML to a PDF document using iTextSharp but it keeps throwing an exception on the document.open statement. When I look at the exception it is set to nothing.

The code (sorry VB) looks like this:

```
        Dim pdfFS As FileStream = New FileStream("<validfullfilename>", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
        Dim pdfDocument As New pdf.PdfDocument
        Dim pdfWriter As pdf.PdfWriter
        pdfWriter = pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, pdfFS)
        pdfDocument.Open()
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument` you need to use `iTextSharp.text.Document()`.

Comment: Thanks Chris that solved it. 
Strange that the exception thrown is nothing though!